# When creating an algorithm for linked lists, why must you be careful about the order in which you change the references?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

My guess would be that Lists, such as Linked Lists have an order in which the Nodes are placed. That means one Node points to the next. 
(I do need more detail or a better answer)

Answer (score 3):

Consider a linked list with this node structure:

```
Node
    int value;
    Node next;
```

And your list contains:

```
1 -> 3 -> 7 -> null
```

So the `next` pointer for the node with value `1` points to the node with the value `3`, etc.

Now, say you want to insert a new node with value `2` between `1` and `3`. The way to do that, is to make the new node point to `3`, and then make the existing node (`1`) point to the new node.

If you were to make `1` point to `2` first, then you overwrite the reference to the `3` node, and the `3` node is lost.